# Drawing shapes; getContext error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("plot");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 175, 40);
}
```

and i keep getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null"

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with your HTML code. Can you show your markup?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for mentioning the HTML I never had thought to look there...